Http Status Code Issue after configuring SpringSecurity
I'm using spring boot v3.2.3 with the following dependencies
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

Here my security config
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable).authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/send").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));

        return http.build();
    }

The problem is that I always get an 401 error code !
Based on the following log, I should get 400 http status code
2024-04-02T09:54:35.188+02:00 DEBUG 1930 --- [tpmc1000] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.method.HandlerMethod             : Could not resolve parameter [0] in public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Void> com.carrefour.fr.tpmc.controller.TransPelicanController.sendFile(com.carrefour.fr.tpmc.dto.FilePayload) throws com.carrefour.fr.tpmc.exception.FunctionalException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `byte[]` from String "": Unexpected end of base64-encoded String: base64 variant 'MIME-NO-LINEFEEDS' expects padding (one or more '=' characters) at the end. This Base64Variant might have been incorrectly configured
2024-04-02T09:54:35.189+02:00  WARN 1930 --- [tpmc1000] [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `byte[]` from String "": Unexpected end of base64-encoded String: base64 variant 'MIME-NO-LINEFEEDS' expects padding (one or more '=' characters) at the end. This Base64Variant might have been incorrectly configured]
2024-04-02T09:54:35.189+02:00 DEBUG 1930 --- [tpmc1000] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 400 BAD_REQUEST
2024-04-02T09:54:35.190+02:00 DEBUG 1930 --- [tpmc1000] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-04-02T09:54:35.194+02:00 DEBUG 1930 --- [tpmc1000] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /error
2024-04-02T09:54:35.194+02:00 DEBUG 1930 --- [tpmc1000] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-04-02T09:54:35.206+02:00 DEBUG 1930 --- [tpmc1000] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8080/error?continue to session

Even when I throw a custom exception with a specific status, I already get 401!! What's wrong with my configuration ?
    public FunctionalException(String message) {
        super(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, message);
    }


You get an error and get redirected to /errror, /error isn't in your permitAll list.

and this behavior is documented in the spring boot docs under error management https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#web.servlet.spring-mvc.error-handling
